Balanced rank-1 decomposition
Given square $n\times n$ positive definite matrix $A$, how to do I find $n\times n$ matrix $Y$ with rows $\{y_i\}$ satisfying the following?
$$\begin{cases}
    \mathbf{y}_i^\top \mathbf{y}_j = A_{ij} & \text{for all } i \leq j \\
    \|\mathbf{y}_i\|^2 = 1 & \text{for all } i
\end{cases}$$
Does this reduce to any known optimization problems? (related question on math.SE)

This can only have a solution if all $|A_{ij}|\le1$ for $i\neq j$ and $A_{ii}=1$. That's because $|\mathbf y_i^T \mathbf y_j|\le |\mathbf y_i| |\mathbf y_j| = 1$.

voted to close as duplicate of https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/44666/inverting-fx-xt-x-for-d-times-d-x-with-unit-norm-rows (also by me)
