Inverting $f(X)=X X^T$ for $d\times d\ X $ with rows of unit norm
Suppose all rows of $d\times d$ matrix $X$ have unit norm and $A=XX^T$. Given $A$, how do I obtain $X$, up to an orthogonal transformation?
I've asked this on math.SE but no answer for 6 days, hence curious if the strong linear-algebra background of this forum can help.

I answered this over at math.stack. I think it was simply an issue with you using the SVD. But I am not sure since I do not fully understand your mathematica code. The "inversion" is unique up to an orthogonal matrix $Q\in O(d)$. I think that if $A$ has repeating eigenvalues, then there is also some freedom in how $V$ is chosen in the subspaces corresponding to eigenvalues with higher multiplicity than $1$. Although maybe that is already accounted for by $Q$, I am not certain. In any case, you have a unique solution as the square root of $A=X^TX$.

Is the reason you want to do this to solve the normal equations?

You problem is basically the reconstruction of the data given the PCA of the data (More accurately, the Multi Dimensional Scaling (MDS)).
I will add assumption which your data is centered, Namely ${\left\{ \boldsymbol{x}_{i} \in \mathbb{R}^{D} \right\}}_{i = 1}^{d}$ where $\sum {x}_{i} = 0$.
The MDS problem tries to solve:
$$ \arg \min_{\boldsymbol{Z} \in \mathbb{R}^{D \times d}} {\left\| \boldsymbol{K}_{x} - \boldsymbol{Z}^{T} \boldsymbol{Z} \right\|}_{F}^{2} $$
Where $D \leq d$ and $\boldsymbol{K}_{x} = - \frac{1}{2} \boldsymbol{J} \boldsymbol{D}_{x} \boldsymbol{J}$ with ${D}_{i, j} = {\left\| \boldsymbol{x}_{i} - \boldsymbol{x}_{j} \right\|}_{2}^{2}$ (The Distance Matrix).
The matrix ${J} = \boldsymbol{I} - \frac{1}{D} \boldsymbol{1} \boldsymbol{1}^{T}$ is the Centering Matrix.
It turns out that $\boldsymbol{K}_{x} = \tilde{\boldsymbol{X}}^{T} \tilde{\boldsymbol{X}}$ where $\tilde{\boldsymbol{X}} = \boldsymbol{X} \boldsymbol{J}$, namely where each column is centered.
So in case your matrix is indeed composed of centered vectors, all you need is to apply MDS with the input being your matrix $\boldsymbol{A}^{T}$ and the output dimension to be $d$.
Remark: The MDS for this Kernel Matrix matches the PCA as I wrote above. It is solved with EVD (Eigen Value Decomposition) or SVD (Singular Value Decomposition).
